# reset_index acting in an unexpected way - unexpected keyword argument 'names'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, jupyter-notebook

I'm cleaning up a dataset for plotting. Pretty standard stuff, transposing, deleting unnecessary columns, etc.
Here is the code so far:

```
#File name
fname = r'E:\Grad School\Research\BOEM\Data\Grain Size\ForScript\allmyCoresRunTD.csv'

#Read csv file into a dataframe. skips the first row that just has the 'record number'. Also only loads the #Dx rows and not the remainder of the bins.
df = pd.read_csv(fname, index_col=None, skiprows=1, nrows=8)

#Delete 'Average' from Malvern. The script will average the data for us
df.drop(columns = df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith('Average')], inplace=True)
df.drop(columns = df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith('FSH')], inplace=True)
```

This is what the dataframe looks like at this point:
[image: Dataframe after importing and deleting some columns]

I rearrange the data some:

```
#Transpose the data
df2 = df.transpose()

#Change the first row into column names
df2.columns = df2.iloc[0]

#Delete header in first row
df2 = df2.drop('Sample Name', axis=0)
```

And now it looks like this:
[image: Dataframe after much of the clean up]

So then I just want to reset the index and name the new column SampleID.

`df2 = df2.reset_index(names=['SampleID'])`

But instead of moving the index to a column and naming the column SampleID, it gives the following error:
[image: Complete error message]

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[4], line 21
     18 df2 = df2.drop('Sample Name', axis=0)
     20 #Reset the indexes
---> 21 df2 = df2.reset_index(names='SampleID')
     22 #df2['SampleID'] = df2['SampleID'].str.replace('19OCS-', '')
     23 df2['SampleID'] = df2['SampleID'].str.split('.').str[0]

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py:311, in deprecate_nonkeyword_arguments.<locals>.decorate.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    305 if len(args) > num_allow_args:
    306     warnings.warn(
    307         msg.format(arguments=arguments),
    308         FutureWarning,
    309         stacklevel=stacklevel,
    310     )
--> 311 return func(*args, **kwargs)

TypeError: reset_index() got an unexpected keyword argument 'names'
```

I originally wrote this code about 6 months ago and it worked just fine but now it's not working? I only changed the file path in the code now vs 6 months ago.

I can run the line like this:

`df2 = df2.reset_index()`

And it will move the index correctly but, of course, the column is not named.
[image: Dataframe with reset index but wrong column name]

I can use .rename to change the name:

`df2 = df2.rename({'index':'SampleID'}, axis=1)`

[image: Dataframe after using rename instead]

But I can't figure out why the names keyword is not working. I've double checked my syntax and looked at the API and I just cannot figure out why it's giving me this error.

I've tried adding/removing brackets; I've tried specifying the level; I've tried using col_fill.
It's probably something simple I did wrong. Thank you for your time.

Note: It changes from df to df2 after the transpose but I continue working in df2 for the remainder of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that version of pandas you are running is >= 1.5.0. The parameter was introduced in 1.5.0 for [reset_index()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)

```py
import pandas as pd
pd.__version__
```

Comment: Thank you. This was it. I thought Anaconda kept all my libraries up to date but that was not the case. It doesn't help that I'm on a "work" computer that has a weird OS image installed and has weird admin permissions. I ended up having to install mamba in order to get pandas updated correctly in Jupyter Notebook but I got it updated though!